# How to speed up glm in bigdata?

Tags: r, glm

I need help to calculate the prevalence of a disease by geographic region adjusted for maternal age. I am trying to do so using glm on a 409MB matrix of 43 million observations and it has been working for a whole day without an output yet. All variables are categorical. Disease is Y/N. Maternal_age has 4 levels and missing values. Region has 5 levels.

This is the script I am using:

```
model <- glm( disease ~ maternal_age + region, 
  family = binomial (link = "logit"), 
  data = data, 
  na.action = na.omit)
tab_model(model)
```

How can I speed it up?

Comment: you aggregate the data, as shown in the answer below. what you are doing is a serious overkill

Answer (score 2):

I tried this with just a million observations on some made-up data.

```r
set.seed(2301)
dat <- data.frame(
  Maternal_age = sample(1:4, 1e7, replace=TRUE),
  Region = sample(1:5, 1e7, replace=TRUE)
)

reg_eff <- runif(5, -2, 2)
age_eff <- runif(4, -2, 2)
dat$prob <- plogis(reg_eff[dat$Region] + age_eff[dat$Maternal_age])
dat$y <- rbinom(1e7, 1, dat$prob)
```

using a GLM on the observation-lvel data, R took around 30 seconds.

```r
system.time(
 g <- glm(y ~ as.factor(Maternal_age) + as.factor(Region), data=dat, family=binomial))
#   user  system elapsed 
# 27.316   2.986  30.323
```

If you aggregate the data and use the binomial regression in a different way, it's much faster:

```r
system.time({
agg <- dat %>% 
  group_by(Maternal_age, Region) %>% 
  summarise(n = n(), k = sum(y))

g2 <- glm(cbind(k, n-k) ~ as.factor(Maternal_age) + as.factor(Region), data=agg, family=binomial )
})
# summarise()` has grouped output by 'Maternal_age'. You can override using the  `.groups` argument.
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.242   0.014   0.256
```

Here are the model summaries (you can see they're the same):

````r
summary(g2)
# Call:
#   glm(formula = cbind(k, n - k) ~ as.factor(Maternal_age) + as.factor(Region), 
#       family = binomial, data = agg)
# 
# Deviance Residuals: 
#   Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
# -2.0602  -0.5343   0.2477   0.4363   1.2025  
# 
# Coefficients:
#                           Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
# (Intercept)              -0.574283   0.001945 -295.28   <2e-16 ***
# as.factor(Maternal_age)2 -0.618526   0.001917 -322.69   <2e-16 ***
# as.factor(Maternal_age)3  1.391454   0.002193  634.40   <2e-16 ***
# as.factor(Maternal_age)4 -0.447535   0.001909 -234.44   <2e-16 ***
# as.factor(Region)2        1.363770   0.002248  606.70   <2e-16 ***
# as.factor(Region)3        1.693202   0.002317  730.65   <2e-16 ***
# as.factor(Region)4        1.160144   0.002218  523.15   <2e-16 ***
# as.factor(Region)5        0.043136   0.002209   19.52   <2e-16 ***
summary(g)
# 
# Call:
#   glm(formula = y ~ as.factor(Maternal_age) + as.factor(Region), 
#       family = binomial, data = dat)
# 
# Deviance Residuals: 
#   Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
# -2.2753  -0.9617   0.4626   0.9408   1.7075  
# 
# Coefficients:
#                           Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
# (Intercept)              -0.574283   0.001945 -295.28   <2e-16 ***
# as.factor(Maternal_age)2 -0.618526   0.001917 -322.69   <2e-16 ***
# as.factor(Maternal_age)3  1.391454   0.002193  634.40   <2e-16 ***
# as.factor(Maternal_age)4 -0.447535   0.001909 -234.44   <2e-16 ***
# as.factor(Region)2        1.363770   0.002248  606.70   <2e-16 ***
# as.factor(Region)3        1.693202   0.002317  730.65   <2e-16 ***
# as.factor(Region)4        1.160144   0.002218  523.15   <2e-16 ***
# as.factor(Region)5        0.043136   0.002209   19.52   <2e-16 ***```
````

So this indicates the aggregate model is about 120x faster than the observation-level model.

Comment: Many thanks. I guess I am too new using R. I understood your example but did not manage to apply it to my own data that is "factor" from the beginning. Besides, I have checked that the most time-consuming part of my script is the tab_model function to compute profiled confidence intervals.

Comment: The only difference in the implementation is that if `Maternal_age` and `Region` are already factors, the formula you would specify is: `g2 <- glm(cbind(k, n-k) ~ Maternal_age + Region, data=agg, family=binomial )` after aggregating the data. This would also speed up the `tab_model()` call significantly, too.